# Change admin post thumbnail size for custom post type only

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, post-thumbnails

I want to change the size of the featued image for one custom post type only. This is what I currently have:

```
function custom_admin_thumb_size($thumb_size){

    global $post_type;
    if( 'slider' == $post_type ){

        return array(1000,400);

    }else{

        return array(266,266);
    }

}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_size', 'custom_admin_thumb_size');
```

This function does what I expected but I was wondering if there is any better method to call the custom post type "slider" without touching the others.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`admin_post_thumbnail_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_size/) takes three parameters:

1. $thumb_size: selected Thumb Size if you do nothing in the filter.
2. $thumbnail_id: Thumbnail attachment ID.
3. $post: associated WP_Post instance

So you may make use of these parameters to have a better control in your CODE. Use the CODE like below:

```
function custom_admin_thumb_size( $thumb_size, $thumbnail_id, $post ) {
    if( 'slider' === $post->post_type ) {
        return array( 1000, 400 );
    }

    return $thumb_size;
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_size', 'custom_admin_thumb_size', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no filter to do this for just a certain post_type but you can use `get_post_type( esc_attr( $_GET['post'] ) )` to save 1 line of code basically.

You can also take out the else statement since your if statement has a return it won't reach after the if anyway. Other than that this is basically what you do.

```
function custom_admin_thumb_size( $thumb_size ){

    if( 'slider' == get_post_type( esc_attr( $_GET['post'] ) ) ) {

        return array( 1000, 400 );

    }

    return array( 266, 266);

}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_size', 'custom_admin_thumb_size' );
```